# AJAX data response - how to parse html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this response in my AJAX request:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>AJAX request</title>
    <style type="text/CSS">
    * {
    font-family:Courier New;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    1
    </body>
    </html>
```

but in

```
    $.ajax({
    ...
    complete:function(data){
    // data has only <title>AJAX request</title><style type="text/CSS">* {font-family:Courier New;} </style> 1
    }
    ...
    });
```

I can't parse it and how can I get 1 value from it? What I do wrong? I don't get all html tags, only title, style and content of body. How can I fix it?

Comment: How do you test that data contains only title?

Comment: If you read the jQuery docs, it removes all the html, body, and head tags and leaves you with the content. Why are you not passing back the value as JSON or just passing back the value you want? If you do not need the HTML, do not send HTML.

Comment: I'm begginer, I will search in Google what is JSON and how can i use it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to send full HTML via AJAX, but only the data needed to modify the existing DOM because the response gets dropped right after the callback functions are done.

So, if you only need that value (1 in your case), you can send it only, so the full response of your AJAX call would simply be:

```
1
```

and then your `data` variable would have the value of 1, of course.

You can also use JSON (especially, if you're sending more data), like:

```
{
  "value": 1,
  "somethingElse": "some value here"
}
```

etc.